# Installing APK by sending Intent to another service in Android 10

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I've got a long running application in a kiosk mode, I will call it 'main app'.
Additionally to that, there is another app installed on a device which manages the updates, I will call it 'updater app'. It's a service running in the background + activity which I use for 'debugging' and testing.

Up until android 9, there was no issue with it. The background service would receive info about update, would download it, inform the main app about update ready and when the main app was in a state which would allow an update it would send an intent and start the update.

With Android 9 and 10 things got a bit messy.
I had to add additional permissions, had to add file provider but in the end I got it to work through my 'testing' activity where I push a button and the app will launch download manager and after a successful download, it will launch the installer of the app. Cool.
Unfortunately, this only works when called from the activity of the 'updater'.
If I switch back to my main app and call intent to launch the installation, there is nothing happening - no user prompt whatsoever. I mean: my app sends intent to start the installation and the only thing I can see in logcat is the following warning:

```
2021-05-28 21:48:33.997 31553-31553/<updater_app> I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:3253066
2021-05-28 21:48:34.006 1590-1626/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://<updater_app>.provider/downloads/prod-e470aba2f-6.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000001 cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStart} from uid 10235
2021-05-28 21:48:34.007 1590-1626/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Background activity start [callingPackage: <updater_app>; callingUid: 10235; isCallingUidForeground: false; isCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; realCallingUid: 10235; isRealCallingUidForeground: false; isRealCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; originatingPendingIntent: null; isBgStartWhitelisted: false; intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://<updater_app>.provider/downloads/prod-e470aba2f-6.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000001 cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStart }; callerApp: ProcessRecord{d1ea9eb 31553:<updater_app>/u0a235}]
```

I assume there are some more restrictions to take care of, but I don't know where to look for more info. I would be grateful for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: "my app sends intent to start the installation" -- have you tried `PackageInstaller`? `ACTION_VIEW` is deprecated for package installation, and you seem to be trying to do the package installation from the background (which will be a problem with `startActivity()`, as the error indicates).

Comment: The same is not a problem on earlier versions of android where it simply launches the installation. From what I could see PackageInstaller can be used only on a rooted device?

Comment: "From what I could see PackageInstaller can be used only on a rooted device?" -- [`PackageInstaller` has been available for ordinary apps since Android 5.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller).